# Error using push.js in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, notifications, push.js

I'm trying to make some browser notifications with push.js library and vb.net 
[image: Image of my notification]

The notification works but my problem is I want multiple notifications at same time, if I need it. the data is taken from my database and usually it'll be more than one data row.

My problem is, it only show one notification

```
For Each t_dtt_row As DataRow In t_dtt_notificaciones.Rows
            str_url_img = "http://finalbca.16mb.com/homepageimages/notificationicon.png"
            If t_dtt_row("nuevo") Then
                t_str_script = "Push.create('Tienes una nueva notificación', {" & _
                               "body: '" & t_dtt_row("notificacion") & "'," & _
                               "icon: '" & str_url_img & "'," & _
                               "timeout: 6000" & _
                               "}); "
            End If
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "notificar", t_str_script, True)
        Next
```

I'm using a "for" but I only get one notification this is an example of what I need [image]

Some ideas? if i do it with html or aspx and js and fixded information works but when I include it with vb.net only shows one.

Comment: Oh my god don't print javascript like this. Make an ajax call or something.

Comment: I apreciate your opinion I did it like this cause it works, It is a way to execute js from vb.net, Can tou give an example? thank for answer

Comment: are you sure you don't have more than one...and they are all appearing in the same spot?

Comment: Yes, Im' sure I think it is for the way I excecute js from vb with  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(..., let me explain I have a datatable with info from database when I excecute the push for the notification only work with first row but it doesn't show the others,  debuged in visual studio and this assumes that work but in the browser only show one notification